# php and node js - twitch view bot

Tags: view, stream, bots, twitch

I have created a twitch robot with php and node js language, which I had a problem with in the view bot. I created fake twitch accounts. I entered the robot with an ID client. Went and went live, but the live I go to is neither a view nor a user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.